# Stripe rails environmental variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, stripe-payments

I am really stuck with this, I am just not sure what is wrong.

I have installed all the code found in the guide found at https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

The problem is, when I attempt to run the following rails command:

```
$ PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_IER4R7474667R7 SECRET_KEY=sk_test_KUDFN847R84 rails s
```

I get the following error:

```
'PUBLISHABLE_KEY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$ export PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_IER4R7474667R7
$ export SECRET_KEY=sk_test_KUDFN847R84
$ rails s
```

They syntax specified in the tutorial works for rails 3.

Bonus Tip: In case that is your staging/prod stripe key, change it.

If you are using Windows, you can use this:

```
$ set PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_IER4R7474667R7
$ set SECRET_KEY=sk_test_KUDFN847R84
$ rails s
```

Comment: what's the error that you are getting? Did you execute all of them in the same terminal window?

Comment: The error I get is:                                                                 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

Comment: What OS are you using? I assumed linux.

Comment: Windows 7, my friend.

Comment: Try set instead of export. $ set PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_IER4R7474667R7  
$ set SECRET_KEY=sk_test_KUDFN847R84